# C++ shared_ptr, how can i return reference to an object from shared pointer created inside a method?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, shared-ptr

i am new to shared pointers. I would like to have a method which returns reference to an object. The object will be created inside a method by make_shared and also stored in a vector as a shared pointer of base class. I guess my code is not the best way to do it. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

```
class A {
public:
};

class B : public A {
public:
};

class Factory {
public:
    B& createA() {
        std::shared_ptr<B> b = std::make_shared<B>();
        container.push_back(b);
        return *b;
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>      container;
};

int main() {
    Factory     factory;

    B&          b = factory.createA();
    //  work with B here...
}
```

Comment: Your example seems reasonable.  Don't actually need shared_ptr in this case, unique_ptr would work fine, since the Factory instance owns the B instances.  This example doesn't use polymorphism, but polymorphism seems to be implied. For polymorphism to work, should have virtual member functions (presumably omitted from the example code as superfluous) and the base class should have a virtual destructor.

Comment: @Eljay, thanks,  but my compiler is complaining about the return statement, that it is returning pointer which is allocated on stack...

Comment: `auto ptr = b.get();` and `return *ptr;` to avoid the compiler complaint.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Which compiler options?

Comment: Visual Studio C++, Level W3